# Does SQL standard allows whitespace between function names and parenthesis

Tags: sql, standards, standards-compliance

Checking few RDBMS I find that things like

```
SELECT COUNT (a), SUM (b)  
FROM TABLE
```

are allowed (notice space between aggregate functions and parenthesis).

Could anyone provide a pointer to SQL standard itself where this is defined (any version will do)?

EDIT:
The above works in postgres, mysql needs `set sql_mode = "IGNORE_SPACE";` as defined [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) (for full list of functions that are influenced with this server mode see in [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/function-resolution.html) ref).
MS SQL is reported to accept the above.

Also, it seems that the answer is most likely in the [standard](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html#query%20specification). I can follow the [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) regarding the regular symbols and terms, but I get lost when it comes to the definition of whitespace and separators in that part of the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; the white space between tokens is substantially ignored.  The only exception is, officially, with adjacent string literal concatenation - but the standard is weirder than any implementation would be.

See: http://savage.net.au/SQL/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the standards. Looking at the grammar if I can work it out.

Comment: The question is whether white space **between aggregate function name and parenthesis** is ignored (according to the STANDARD), and where exactly this is defined. Is this the relevant part of the grammar? (see next comment)

Comment: <aggregate function>    ::= 
         COUNT <left paren> <asterisk> <right paren> [ <filter clause> ]
     |     <general set function> [ <filter clause> ]
     |     <binary set function> [ <filter clause> ]
     |     <ordered set function> [ <filter clause> ]  
  
 <general set function>    ::=   <set function type> <left paren> [ <set quantifier> ] <value expression> <right paren>  
  
Because if so, it seems to me that this says a space is NOT allowed, but I am far from familiar with grammars.

Comment: It is a general rule of thumb; except within 'strings' and as needed to separate tokens and keywords, white space is immaterial to the interpretation of SQL.  You won't find that in the BNF; it would be documented separately.  You could write each token on its own line with a blank line after it and the SQL would be interpreted the same as if it is all on one line with no unnecessary spaces at all.

Comment: The detailed information can be found in 9075-2 (SQL/Foundation) in section 5.2 of the 2003 standard.  However, it is not simple to understand (it spans syntax rules 3-11), and includes references to another part of the standard.   You can hunt `<separator>`, `<token>`, `<white space>` in the grammar referenced, but that doesn't give you all the verbiage.

Comment: And is it your conclusion that the space between aggregate function name and left parenthesis is not an exception to the "rule of thumb" (i.e. it is allowed)? (this is a genuine question, just in case it may sound sarcastic it is not meant to be at all)

Comment: Yes - there is nothing in the standard to prohibit the appearance of spaces between an aggregate function name and the open parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT COUNT   (*)
  FROM TABLE
```

...while one space between `COUNT` and `(*)` on MySQL causes a MySQL 1064 error (syntax error).  I don't have Oracle or Postgres handy to test.

Whatever the standard may be, it's dependent on implementation in the vendor and version you are using.

Comment: actually it will work in mysql as well if you set sql_mode = "IGNORE_SPACE"; (which IMHO tries to bring it closer to standard)

Answer (score -1):

I can't provide a pointer, but I believe that white space like that is ignored.

I know that it is in T-SQL, and about 80% certain about MySQL's implementation.