# populate drop down list from mysql database and don't repeat values

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

I am populating a drop down menu from mysql database. It works well, But I want it not to repeat values. (i.e if some value is N times in database it comes only once in the drop down list)

Here is my code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db ("database");

$sql = "SELECT year FROM data";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='year'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['year'] . "'>" . $row['year'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: sorry this is a better link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476307/how-does-mysql-define-distinct-in-reference-documentation

Comment: "Quick Quick please" is not a very nice way to ask volunteers for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) in your query.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT year FROM data";
```

Answer (score 4):

just change Your query. is better

$sql = "SELECT distinct year FROM data";

Answer (score 2):

Another technique:

```
select year from table group by year
```

Answer (score 1):

in PHP side you have to do this

```
$all_data = array();

echo "<select name='year'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 array_push($all_data,$row["column"]);
}
$all_data = array_unique($all_data);
foreach($all_data as $columns => $values){
 print("<option value='$value'>$value</option>");
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple trick. Take a boolean array. Which value has not come in list print it in list and which value has come in list already once, set it as *true* through indexing the boolean array.

 Set a condition, if *boolean_array[ value ]* is not *true*, then show *value* in list. Otherwise, don't.

```
mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db ("database");

$sql = "SELECT year FROM data";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='year'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    if($bul[$row['year']] != true){
        echo "<option value='" . $row['year'] . "'>" . $row['year'] . "        </option>";
        $bul[$row['year']] = true;
   }
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```