# Speeding up this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a pretty large database of 20 million records of geographic points, and its growing every day.

```
[id (int)] [group (int)] [latitude (double)] [longitude(double)]
[1]        [1]           [22.365598]         [12.55678]
[2]        [1]           [22.365548]         [12.55238]
[3]        [2]           [24.665348]         [13.10238]
```

Now I want every point inside a given boudingbox.The boudingbox has the size of South Africa and the query should return about 7.000 results. But it takes 30 seconds to get the results.

The query is:

```
SELECT distinct(group), id from `table`
where (latitude between -95.22 and 36.458 and longitude between -51.939 and 103.833);
```

The index is [latitude, longitude] (btree).

How on earth can I speed this up?

---

**EDIT**

What I want to accomplish

The database contains a large set of polygons. Say for example National parks.
Each node in the polygon sits in this table. Now I want to check if a National park is within the range of an given position.

The Id is the node id, the group is the polygon it belongs to, and the latitude and longitude is the position of the node.

---

When I don't use distinct, the query will finish in 3 seconds but has 900.000 results to return. which is a lot to handle in the rest of the code.

---

**Sollution**

As Gordon Linoff in his answer says: it is a realy large surface. The query is used for some realy detailed results. With this large surface I shouldnt use all the nodes from all polygons but use a centeroid of the polygon.
When I need detailed results for small surfaces, this query runs fast enough.

So I think I stick with that.

Comment: I wonder if adding Group to the index would help. But then you've almost duplicated the table in the index.

Comment: longitude and latitude  indexes should be btree for between query

Comment: How fast is the query if you ommit `distinct(group)`?

Comment: `distinct` is NOT a function. Is the questions sql valid? looks invalid to me.  for examle see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476307/how-does-mysql-define-distinct-in-reference-documentation I would certainly try running without the distinct keyword

Comment: What result are you trying to get, can you post an example?  `DISTINCT` does not act like a function, though your query's `distinct(group)` makes it seem like you want it to be used like one. `DISTINCT` is applied over the full rowset returned to deduplicate rows having _all_ the same columns. Using it the way you have does not even look syntactically valid for MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [The Range Access Method for Multiple-Part Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-multi-part):

> The optimizer attempts to use additional key parts to determine the interval as long as the comparison operator is [`=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal), [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), or [`IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null). If the operator is [`>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_greater-than), [`<`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than), [`>=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_greater-than-or-equal), [`<=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than-or-equal), [`!=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal), [`<>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal), [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), or [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), the optimizer uses it but considers no more key parts.

In other words, MySQL uses your index only to find records whose `latitude` falls within the specified range—it then fetches those records from the table and scans through them to perform the filter on `longitude`.

The reason that MySQL does this is obvious if you consider how a [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is structured:

```
                          Bd
                 ________/  \_______
                /                   \
               Ad                   Cd
            __/  \__             __/  \__
           /        \           /        \
          Ab        Bb         Cb        Db
         /  \      /  \       /  \      /  \
        Aa  Ac    Ba  Bc     Ca  Cc    Da  Dc
```

Filtering the first key part for a range (e.g. where the first character is `BETWEEN 'B' AND 'C'` in the example above, but the latitude criterion in your case) is very simple, because the tree is already sorted with respect to the first key part:

```
                          Bd
                 ________/  \_______
                /                   \
                \                   Cd
                 \__             __/
                    \           /
                    Bb         Cb
                   /  \       /  \
                  Ba  Bc     Ca  Cc
```

But the resulting pruned tree cannot help when filtering on the second key part (e.g. where the second character is `BETWEEN 'b' AND 'c'` in this example, but the longitude criterion in your case) because it is *not* sorted with respect to the second key part.  By contrast, had the first key part been filtered for an *exact* match (rather than a range) then the resulting pruned tree *would* then already be sorted by the second key part.

Thus B-trees cannot help so much with locating multidimensional ranges.  The [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) is an alternative data structure that is much better suited to problems of this sort.  MySQL is capable of creating R-tree indexes using its [spatial extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/spatial-extensions.html):

1. Create a new column of a [spatial data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/spatial-datatypes.html) (e.g. `POINT`) that will hold your coordinate data and [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html) it:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `table`
     ADD coordinates POINT,
     ADD SPATIAL INDEX (coordinates);
   ```
2. Populate that column from your existing data:

   ```
   UPDATE `table` SET coordinates = Point(longitude, latitude);
   ```

   You may want to define triggers and/or views to assist with further migration.
3. Perform your search:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT `group`, id 
   FROM   `table`
   WHERE  MBRContains(
            MultiPoint(Point(-51.939, -95.22), Point(103.833, 36.458)),
            coordinates
          )
   ```

   What's particularly nice about this approach is that, as of MySQL 5.6.1, you can [use object shapes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html) to perform even more precise searches: e.g. define polygons that exactly represent national boundaries.
4. Update your application to use this new column, for example:

   ```
   SELECT X(coordinates) AS longitude, Y(coordinates) AS latitude FROM `table`
   ```

   You may want to define triggers and/or views to assist with the migration.
5. Drop the old columns:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `table` DROP longitude, DROP latitude;
   ```

However, you should note that MySQL's spatial extensions use Euclidean geometry (whereas, obviously, the Earth is spherical): this shouldn't affect the above operation, but be wary of using it to perform calculations such as distance.

Comment: I should have noted that spatial indexes are currently only supported in MyISAM tables.

Answer (score 1):

First, parentheses don't matter for `distinct`.  So, just write the query as:

```
SELECT distinct `group`, id
from `table`
where latitude between -95.22 and 36.458 and
      longitude between -51.939 and 103.833;
```

This type of query -- with two `between`s -- is not really amenable to indexes.  You *can* try an index on `latitude, longitude` or `longitude, latitude`, and it might offer some small increment in speed.

A better approach is to use spatial indexes.  [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html) is the place to start learning about them.

However, even a spatial index is not likely to be much help.  The areas in your query account for about 1/6 of the earth's surface.  If your point are evenly distributed, then this is over 3 million records that need to be aggregated (for the `select distinct`).  You probably won't have much luck getting really good performance for this query.

Comment: I think I have to simplify the data for large surfaces and use this detailed query only for realy small area's. Thanks

Comment: @user2740744 . . . If you use the spatial extensions, you may find that they have exactly the functions you are looking for -- with reasonable performance.

Comment: I will investigate that further. But as I don't have much knowledge about it, I dont want overrushing implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direkt answer to your question, but if you already use MySQL 5.5 or higher and you have the choice to change your data model I would suggest you make use of the `Point` datatype and add a spatial index

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-spatial-data.html

Otherwise I would suggest you leave out the distinct, since it can be a performance bottleneck sometimes and add a `group by` instead and I would suggest to include `group` into the index, too.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add a field containing an integer field with the index for the exact teritory? Ex. `(latitude between -95.22 and 36.458 and longitude between -51.939 and 103.833);` = 1; `(some other lat/long span)` = 2 etc. Then you just recalculate the values for each record and store the values in the new field. All the new (updated) records can be processed by before insert (update) trigger so that the place integer field is set for every appended (updated record). All the SELECT queries will use this field instead of lat/long double fields.
This will be some redundancy of data but might help you if you have a limited list of territories. You can use the second table for the purpose of storing the list of territories and their id's.