# What are the different between DISTINCT(c1), c2 and DISTINCT c1, c2

Tags: mysql

As the title states, what are the differences between `DISTINCT(c1), c2` and `DISTINCT c1, c2`?

Is the `DISTINCT(c1)` like a function? I didn't find any manual mentioning `DISTINCT` can be a function.

Sample output:

```sql
mysql> create table t1(c1 int, c2 int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.26 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values(1,1),(1,2),(2,4),(2,2),(2,4);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select c1, c2 from t1;
+------+------+
| c1   | c2   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    4 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    2 |    4 |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select distinct(c1), c2 from t1;
+------+------+
| c1   | c2   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    4 |
|    2 |    2 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select distinct c1, c2 from t1;
+------+------+
| c1   | c2   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    4 |
|    2 |    2 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476307/how-does-mysql-define-distinct-in-reference-documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  The difference is that the `select distinct (c1), c2` has extra, unneeded parentheses in the `select` clause.

`DISTINCT` is *not* a function or operator in SQL.  It is a type of `SELECT` statement and it applies to *all* the columns in the `SELECT`.  Parentheses have no relevance.

You can think of it the same way as the `ALL` in `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

No, distinct is not like a function! Its just a kind of select which is similar to what GROUP BY clause is doing.

Distinct will always be applied on the entire row/all the columns specified in the select so it doesn't matter if you add parentheses or not.

Its prefered not to do it with parentheses because it will be harder to read and understand and may mislead to the same question you asked here - does it apply only on the column.